# OAuth1 authenticated calls on Khan Academy's API using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, google-apps-script

I'm pretty new to coding. I'm using Google App Script, which is supposed to be javascript based and a library to manage OAuth1 api authentication. I'm trying to authenticate with the Khan Academy. This script which I got from the google apps site works to a point. The function 'listTweets' takes me to the 'else' branch and logs the url to take me to Khan Academy to grant the script permission to make the call. I accept and am supposed to rerun the function and end up in the 'then' branch of the 'if-then-else' statement. I just keep getting sent down the else. Does anyone know what gives? Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'my key';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = 'my secret';
var PROJECT_KEY = 'my google project key';

function listTweets() {
  var service = getTwitterService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var response = service.fetch('https://www.khanacademy.org//api/v1/user/exercises');
    var tweets = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(tweets);
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.authorize();
    Logger.log('Please visit the following URL and then re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}

function getTwitterService() {
  var service = OAuth1.createService('twitter');
  service.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/access_token')
  service.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token')
  service.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize')
  service.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
  service.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
  service.setProjectKey(PROJECT_KEY);
  service.setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
  service.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties());
  service.setOAuthVersion('1.0');
  return service;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getTwitterService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this page.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this page');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular API, but reading through [their documentation](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Authentication), and looking the [PHP example](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/blob/master/examples/php_test_client/oauth-php/test/oauth_test.php), it appears that they are expecting the OAuth parameters to be passed in the URL rather than the Authorization Header.

By default, the OAuth services use the Authorization header, but this can be over-ridden with `service.setParamLocation('uri-query')`.

Comment: Thanks for talking a look at that I'm going to try to insert that now and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite work. I inserted 'service.setParamLocation('uri-query')' in the last line of the function that builds the service object, right before 'return service;'

Comment: If you're confirmed that the key values are correct, you will need to step through the library's UrlFetch calls and check that their individual results. See [this](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/debugging-external-host-communication-with-urlfetchapp/).

Comment: Mogsdad, thanks so much. My key's are correct because I can actually "accept" letting my script access my Khan Academy account info. Something is not going right with my api call after I "accept". This link looks really promising. I really need so see what is going out from my script. I'll have a chance to work through it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Here's some news: Eric updated [Google's OAuth1 Library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1), it now supports 2-legged OAuth1.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce and track down your problem. Funny enough, it ends up being a single-character fix (after the `setParamLocation` fix already mentioned): you just need to use OAuth version "1.0a" instead of "1.0". OAuth version 1.0a changed some of the details of how the OAuth callback works to fix a security issue, and I guess this OAuth library only includes the callback URL in the request_token step when using OAuth 1.0a. The KA API always uses the callback specified in the request_token step, so the previous version of the app script was never running the callback.

Here's some code that works for me:

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'FILL ME IN';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = 'FILL ME IN';
var PROJECT_KEY = 'FILL ME IN';

function listExercises() {
  var service = getKhanAcademyService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var response = service.fetch('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/user/exercises');
    var exercises = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(exercises);
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.authorize();
    Logger.log('Please visit the following URL and then re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}

function getKhanAcademyService() {
  var service = OAuth1.createService('khanAcademy');
  service.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/access_token')
  service.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token')
  service.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize')
  service.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
  service.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
  service.setProjectKey(PROJECT_KEY);
  service.setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
  service.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties());
  service.setOAuthVersion('1.0a');
  service.setParamLocation('uri-query');
  return service;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getKhanAcademyService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this page');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this page');
  }
}
```

Comment: Alan, thanks a ton. I tried to run your script with my key's. I hit a snag. When I try to build the service object by running "getKhanAcademyService", the script dies on the first line of that function var service = OAuth1.createService('khanAcademy');  The error is "OAuth1 is not defined". I was looking for some small syntax error because on my original script the statement var service = OAuth1.createService('twitter'); didn't catch any errors. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me with this.

Comment: You need to add the OAuth1 library as a dependency. See the instructions here: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1#setup

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. I forgot to do that on my new script. It works like a charm. Thanks so much!